# Removing all blank lines but not comments in Ruamel.yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am using the Ruamel Python library to programmatically update human-edited YAML files.

I have data like this:

```
---
a:
  b: '1'
  c: "2"

  d: 3
  # Comment.
  e: 4
```

I don't know in advance where the comments will be and where the blank lines will be.

I need to reset this to:

```
---
a:
  b: '1'   
  c: "2"
  d: 3
  # Comment.
  e: 4
```

I can see from [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172399/modifying-yaml-using-ruamel-yaml-adds-extra-new-lines) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198379/how-can-i-add-a-blank-line-before-some-data-using-ruamel-yaml) how I could simply remove all comments, but I don't know how to look inside the CommentToken to see if it contains a comment that I need to preserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earlier versions of ruamel.yaml would not preserve empty lines, it is however relatively easy to get that behaviour back by stripping the newlines at the point where all comments pass through when they are emitted: `Emitter.write_comment()` in `ruamel/yaml/emitter.py`. Luckily lines consisting off spaces followed by a newline are already reduced to just the newline. Essentially, instead of searching your data for attached comments and figuring out how to rewrite them, you let the comments come to you.

I included some more empty comment line cases to test the functionality:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
a:
  b: '1'
  # comment followed by empty lines


  c: "2"

  d: 3
  # Comment.
  e: 4


  # empty lines followed by comment
  f: 5

  # comment between empty lines

  g: |+
    an empty line within a multi-line literal

    with a trailing empty line that is not stripped

  h: 6

# final top level comment
"""

# rename the comment writer
ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment_org = ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment


# define your own comment writer that calls the orginal if the comment is not empty
def strip_empty_lines_write_comment(self, comment):
    # print('{:02d} {:02d} {!r}'.format(self.column, comment.start_mark.column, comment.value))
    comment.value = comment.value.replace('\n', '')
    if comment.value:
        self.write_comment_org(comment)

# install
ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment = strip_empty_lines_write_comment

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str, preserve_quotes=True)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
a:
  b: '1'
  # comment followed by empty lines
  c: "2"
  d: 3
  # Comment.
  e: 4
  # empty lines followed by comment
  f: 5
  # comment between empty lines
  g: |+
    an empty line within a multi-line literal

    with a trailing empty line that is not stripped

  h: 6
# final top level comment
```

This will of course affect all dumped data after "installing" `strip_empty_lines_write_comment`. If you have need in your program to also dump data **with** empty lines, then you need to subclass `StrippingEmitter` based on `Emitter` and make a `StrippingRoundTripDumper` (like `RoundTripDumper` in `ruamel/yaml/dumper.py`) using that subclass.

(You can of course remove the commented out debugging print statement from the code)

Comment: Thanks for your help as always. Unfortunately, I can't do it this way, because I do sometimes need to keep the blank lines. The problem I have actually is that Ruamel.yaml is adding blank lines that I don't want in some contexts when I copy data from one YAML file to another, and I haven't understood why. In any case, I need to be able to control the comments and spacing on data that my tool is changing, but without changing the formatting that is put there by people not using my tool.

Comment: Generic control over the comments is non-trivial and will open another can of worms. Are you allowing your tool users to comment? If you don't, or don't want to keep those comments, you could patch the comments from the original on the user updated data, that is relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

It does not solve the problem specifically as I asked it, but for what it's worth, I ended up with this:

```
data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str, preserve_quotes=True)

space, no_space = map(lambda x:
    [None, None, ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken(x, \
        ruamel.yaml.error.CommentMark(0), None), None], ['\n\n', '\n'])

for key in data['a'].ca.items:
    data['a'].ca.items[key] = no_space

last = data['a'].keys()[-1]
data['a'].ca.items[last] = space
```

i.e. I'm just giving up on keeping any non-space comments for now.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ended up with something like the following. This will remove any comment that is empty when stripped, ie is only whitespace. Comments that include any actual content will be retained.

```
import ruamel.yaml

def monkeypatch_emitter():
    ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.old_write_comment = ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment

    def write_comment(self, comment, *args, **kwargs):
        if comment.value.strip():
            self.old_write_comment(comment, *args, **kwargs)

    ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment = write_comment

def main():
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    # do yaml stuff here

if __name__ == '__main__:
    monkeypatch_emitter()
    main()
```

There may have been some changes to the `write_comment` signature since the answer above was added, as it was failing due to the occasional presence of a 'pre' keyword argument. The code above should pass through any extra arguments should this change again in the future.