# ruamel creating empty blank lines after comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm struggling with doing a roundtrip parsing of a YAML file using ruamel.
Below is an example YAML file, `input.yaml`:

```yaml
##### Header comment ####
key: #comment1
  key2: val2
```

Below is the python code

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml
input = Path("input.yaml")
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(input)
yaml.dump(data,Path("someoutput.yaml"))
```

This creates an output file with blank newline after each comment

```yaml
##### Header comment ####

key: #comment1

  key2: val2
```

I tried recursively going through each comment (ca.comment) and stripping it but was not successful in that

I've gone through multiple questions but the closest I could found was
[Modifying YAML using ruamel.yaml adds extra new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172399/modifying-yaml-using-ruamel-yaml-adds-extra-new-linesw). However in this question the comment itself has a newline so not related to my problem

I'm using:

```
ruamel.yaml==0.17.32
python 3.9
Windows
```

Comment: Do you happen to be on on windows? Does your input have `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: Yes, it is windows so each line ending has \r\n

Comment: I'll try to find a windows machine. I can't reproduce this on macOS or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handed a `pathlib.Path` instance as parameter to `YAML().load()` this file will be opened `rb`, and the processing of `\r\n` ending should be done by the scanner.

It looks like that doesn't work correctly, so I recommend trying:

```
data = yaml.load(input.open())
```

and/or:

```
yaml.dump(data,Path("someoutput.yaml").open('w'))
```